# Grant Security Reader role to an Azure Service Principal in az cli

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, terraform-provider-azure, service-principal

I'm trying to allow a service principal in Azure to read from Azure Active Directory in order to perform lookups against AAD when using Terraform.

I'm pretty sure that the role required is the Security Reader role, however, I'm not sure what the context needs to be in order to add the service principal to the role.  I'm assuming it is on the tenantId, but not sure the format that the `az role assignment` command then needs?

The code I'm currently using is as follows:-

```
sp=$(az ad sp list --query "[?displayName=='[my app]'].appId" --output tsv)
tenantId=$(az account show --query tenantId --output tsv)
az role assignment create --role "Secuity Reader" --assignee $sp --scope $tenantId
```

But this does not validate against the scope correctly, so it's clearly not just the tenant id.  I know for subscription level scope it would be `/subscriptions/[subscription id]...` etc, but I don't know what the format would be for tenancy level permissions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `az role assignment` command is a subscription based command, using this you can only add assignments to specific subscriptions so called RBAC (Resource Based Access Control) assignments.

What you are searching for is adding the role to the Azure AD.

To show you to add a this is how you add an AAD Role to a user with PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0

```
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember
   -ObjectId <String>
   -RefObjectId <String>
   [-InformationAction <ActionPreference>]
   [-InformationVariable <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

This is how to add an RBAC role with PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-4.4.0

```
New-AzRoleAssignment
   -ObjectId <String>
   [-Scope <String>]
   -RoleDefinitionName <String>
   [-AllowDelegation]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

It is two totally different things using two different modules. I don't know if there is an addon to CLI to support the AzureAD module.

Comment: Ok thanks for the powershell link. Unfortunately we're currently running this on linux and don't have powershell installed. Also, the error message for az role assignment is a little confusing as it does mention being an invalid subscription or tenancy based resource. Oh well!

Comment: then you can use it through the portal using the Cloud Shell

Comment: @MatthewDarwin its like you are trying to give the key to your car and use it to open your house. Its two different locations one key doesnt work to the other. The "az role assignment" is used to give RBAC (The car) permissions while you want to give Azure AD (the house) permissions.

Comment: @MatthewDarwin on the Subscription you have one role named "Security Reader" and on the AAD you have another role named "Security Reader" those are different roles and gives access to different resources.

Comment: Whilst I understand your analogy, it doesn't make sense given that you can do all of this in the portal, or in powershell.  The az cli should have exactly the same power as either of those: its the same thing really, just accessed in a slightly different manner.

Comment: @MatthewDarwin updated with more information in the answer

Comment: Got you, thanks for the explanation.  I haven't looked recently (about to do so after typing this) as no longer with the same company and not working on Azure at the moment, AWS land instead, but at the time I don't remember there being anything for AzureAD in the az cli.  Which is a shame, as I dislike powershell these days, and the az cli behaves very similarly to the aws cli - meaning its a much easier transfer between the two. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `az rest` or `curl` and follow the documentation for more details
[Assign an Azure role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest#assign-an-azure-role)

something like this,

```
az rest --method PUT --resource "https://management.azure.com/" --uri "https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/{roleAssignmentId}?api-version=2015-07-01" --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body $jsonBody
```

use jsonBody variable to build json Object as per documentation link.